# add-migration 'InitialModel' is showing database access error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

After enabling the migrations, I tried to add the first migration using  add-migration 'InitialModel'. I am attaching the The MyDBContext.cs file code.

```
{
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } // My domain models
    }
}
```

An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.

Comment: As the tutorial was showing, I did not create any db and using code first approach. I also tried following instructions of page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings. please help

Comment: The solution is identified.... I installed the entity framework from the nudget package manager which was 6.1.0 but installing it from the console it became 6.2.0. Now there is no issue.